# Remove unnecessary frameworks in Xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-project

I have been writing iOS applications and completed a project with a lot of frameworks. Now I am using it as a template to start a new project that requires less functionality and hence I should be able to reduce the frameworks required, and hopefully reduce build time and size of project.

Question:
Is there a quick way to check which frameworks are no longer required within the project?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7847558/xcode-removing-unused-frameworks/7847881#7847881

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing unused frameworks in Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7847558/removing-unused-frameworks-in-xcode)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is a better way than removing the framework, building, and seeing if there are link errors. You might be able to write a bash script but it's probably more work than it's worth.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly not. The quick way is to remove all the frameworks, look for build errors and add back in the necessary frameworks.

Answer (score -1):

search  in the project files(cmd+shift+F).i.e whether you are imported any files related to the frameworks.

Comment: there are lots of calls that need no import of the library, so this (i just tried it) makes a mess