# Parse Starter Project LogIn and Register View Controllers Errors

Tags: ios, parse-platform

When I tried to use the Parse Starter Project (I downloaded it and installed it as per the instructions, but I don't have a developer's license yet, so no push notifications), I got six errors, all about referencing twitter Mach-O Link errors.
Here they are:

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:

```
"_ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter", referenced from:
  -[PF_Twitter getLocalTwitterAccountAsync] in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_ACAccountStore", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_SLComposeViewController", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_SLRequest", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
"_SLServiceTypeTwitter", referenced from:
  -[PF_Twitter getAccessTokenForReverseAuthAsync:localTwitterAccount:] in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
  -[PF_Twitter getLocalTwitterAccountAsync] in Parse(PF_Twitter.o) 
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Are you trying to access twitter without installing the twitter SDK?  Parse has twitter helpers, but they are still dependent on the twitter SDK.

Comment: Nope I didn't install anything except the base Parse SDK, then in the Parse tutorials there was a section on user interface, and then on log in screens. I followed the step(s) posted there.

Comment: Are you trying to use twitter login?

Comment: Nope, I just want to use the default log in, username password and create an account (with the forgot password if possible).  Nothing fancy,

Comment: Not sure what's going on.  You're missing the architecture for the i386 architecture which is the simulator.  Can you replicate this on a device?  Have you checked that you're on the latest version of parse?

Comment: Would it be better if we were to uninstall the Parse, and do a complete reinstall from the latest version? (We used the version on the parse website available today) Sorry I'm new to all of this.

Comment: No problem, everybody's got to start somewhere.  It's difficult to diagnose problems sometimes without seeing the whole project.

Comment: I have another problem with another i386 Architecture in another file, could you help?

Comment: I'm not really sure what's going on with your project, or why this isn't working.  I'd need to know a lot more details and even then, I'm not really sure.  Can you try starting over and seeing if you get the same errors.

Comment: this is just that I made a new project, it's saying 2 duplicate symbols for architecture i386, and I can't find any duplicates....

Comment: Check the source folder in finder.

Comment: addWorkIMG.png
AppDelegate.h
AppDelegate.m
Base.lproj
browseBGimg.png
Default.png
en.lproj
GenericKeychain_Prefix.pch
Graphic Design Demonstration-Info.plist
Graphic Design Demonstration-Prefix.pch
homeBGImg.png
homeIconFinal1.png
iamge2.png
iamge3.png
Images.xcassets
Info.plist
Localizable.strings
logInViewController.h
logInViewController.m
main.m
MainWindow.xib
puppyIcon.png
signInController.h
signInController.m
slideInMenuController.h
slideInMenuController.m
ViewController.h
ViewController.m Nothing is the same...

Comment: I can't tell what's going on from that, it could be a number of things.  Try cleaning everything, closing everything completely, restarting your computer, and firing up a fresh project.

Comment: I found the source folder for architecture i386, by copying the path specified by the error message in Xcode.  There were several .o files which apparently were conflicting, however whenever I deleted one, and ran the program, it would replace it. What do I do? Also I've cleaned it and closed everything and restarted my computer. Thanks

Answer (score 52):

I had this same issue. The login related classes for parse require you to add two additional frameworks beyond what is listed in their quick start documentation:

```
Social.framework
Accounts.framework
```

These frameworks are part of iOS. Simply go to the projects **Build Phases->Link Binary with Libraries** and add them. I hope you find this helpful.

Comment: i wish they would update their documentation. another issue i've experienced recently is if you use cocoapods, you'll have some undefined symbols for the facebook SDK unless you manually pull in facebook. these two issues have made the parse starter project more difficult than necessary.

Answer (score 6):

They didn't mention in the Quick start this two.

```
Social.framework
Accounts.framework
```

This library has been included in the parse.zip, with Bolts we clean the last 4 errors.

```
Bolts.framework
```

Answer (score 5):

I was receiving the exact same error while attempting to complile the Parse Starter project. So I followed the advice in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7847881/3960969, and everything seemed to work.

Basically, all I had to do was remove the reference to and re-install these frameworks:

```
Social.framework
Accounts.framework
```

After that, the project compiled without any errors or warnings.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem. You add the Social.framework then it should solve it.

Answer (score 0):

STTwitter [documentation](https://github.com/nst/STTwitter) says you must include following frameworks to your project.

1. Accounts.framework
2. Social.framework
3. Twitter.framework (iOS only)
4. Security.framework (OS X only)