# Parse Twitter SDK

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I don't want to integrate twitter or Facebook with my Parse app, and i've specified that in the coding of what I want on my login screen.  I have 6 errors coming up: (I'm using Xcode 5 and latest version of Parse SDK)

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter", referenced from:
      -[PF_Twitter getLocalTwitterAccountAsync] in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ACAccountStore", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SLComposeViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SLRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
  "_SLServiceTypeTwitter", referenced from:
      -[PF_Twitter getAccessTokenForReverseAuthAsync:localTwitterAccount:] in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
      -[PF_Twitter getLocalTwitterAccountAsync] in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Presumably you are not linking with the Twitter framework.

Comment: Answer: Add Social.framework

Comment: couldn't find a twitter.framework

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse Starter Project LogIn and Register View Controllers Errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23253410/parse-starter-project-login-and-register-view-controllers-errors)

Answer (score 65):

Under Targets, General, Linked Frameworks and Libraries add:

- Social.framework
- Accounts.framework

Comment: I did this and it hasn't made any difference, there are still 4 errors.

Comment: @WECorps presumably you're still missing the FacebookSDK. If you don't want to include the FacebookSDK, [try this workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18626232/1032372)

Comment: Why aren't these listed on their setup page?

Comment: I was missing Accounts! @livingtech so true!

Comment: Thank you a lot,it helps me

Answer (score 14):

This Match-O error usually come into the picture because you need the the link flag -ObjC.
They usually say that your framework links are messed up. SO first thing is to check they are all linked properly by comparing your left side pane (where you see frameworks) and the target -> Build settings under the Linked Frameworks and Library.

For your particular case, I' d bet you will need to add:

- Social.framework
- FacebookSDK.framework
- Accounts.framework

Hope this helps.

Comment: I couldnt find anything for the FacebookSDK.framwork? Nothing came up

Comment: you have to downlaod it from Facebook, it doesn't come bundled with XCODE. It's here: [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/)  download and drag and drop into your frameworks (left side pane)

Comment: If you don't need the FacebookSDK in your project, you can include [this workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15457136/parse-for-ios-errors-when-trying-to-run-the-app/18626232#18626232)

Comment: facebook is not necessary, just social and accounts

Answer (score 7):

Click on Targets → Your app name → and then the 'Build Phases' tab.
Expand 'Link Binary With Libraries'
Add Social.framework

Edit: may also need to add Accounts.framework

Comment: Adding the Social.framework did reduce the count but still there are errors including :: "_ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter". Tried adding Twitter framework, that didn't help as well.

Comment: Also need to add "Account.Framework". I think the reason these aren't in the Quickstart is that you're supposed to include the Facebook SDK now (which is dumb and their documentation is also unclear about that). Consider [this workaround for the Facebook SDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15457136/parse-for-ios-errors-when-trying-to-run-the-app/18626232#18626232)

Answer (score 4):

Also need to add **Social.framework**, **Accounts.framework**, and, **Twitter.framework** - see below for the complete screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The documentation doesn't seem up to date. To make it work you have to add the *Accounts* framework and also the *Bolts* framework, the latter comes with the Parse sdk.

Answer (score -1):

add those frameworks:

- Social.framework
- Accounts.framework
- CoreData.framework