# Swift Parse PubNub Mach-O Errors

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, cocoapods, pubnub

I am creating an app in using Swift, Parse and PubNub. I used pods to install Parse and PubNub and those appear to be installed just fine. However I get all of these compile errors and am not sure which direction I should be looking to solve them.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_PFObject", referenced from:
  __TMaCSo8PFObject in ViewController.o
  __TMaCSo8PFObject in LogInViewController.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_PFQuery", referenced from:
  __TMaCSo7PFQuery in LogInViewController.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_PFUser", referenced from:
  __TMaCSo6PFUser in SignUpViewController.o
  __TMaCSo6PFUser in ViewController.o
  __TMaCSo6PFUser in LogInViewController.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_PNChannel", referenced from:
  __TMaCSo9PNChannel in ViewController.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_PNConfiguration", referenced from:
  __TMaCSo15PNConfiguration in ViewController.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_Parse", referenced from:
  __TMaCSo5Parse in AppDelegate.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_PubNub", referenced from:
  __TMaCSo6PubNub in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Make sure you are `Import`'ing your frameworks.

Comment: See my previous answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23266338/parse-twitter-sdk/23572069#23572069) to similar issue. That might help you here since Match-O error tend to be generic.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a Swift iOS application that uses the Parse Pod.

I did the following and things to get it compiling:

1. Update to Parse version 1.7.4 in your Podfile
2. In the Pods project, set "Allow non-module includes in Framework modules" to YES

   3. Don't forget to add use_frameworks! to your podfile