# Undefined symbols for architecture arm64 Parse

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to implement parse in my app. The issue here is that I get these strange errors I have no idea of what they mean:

[image]

I have tried to:

1) change architecture, but the latest version of Xcode doesn't let me set my own (e.g. arm64).
2) I have tried to delete a possibly conflicting SDK (Dropbox).
3) I have linked to binary
4) I have added all required frameworks.

No solution worked until now...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, contrary to most cases, you need to remove the `-ObjC` flag from the project if you're not using the Facebook functionality.

Otherwise, if you need the `-ObjC` flag, you will need to include the facebook sdk in your project

Comment: How on earth did you figure it out? Have you ever had this exact problem?

Comment: Its a common problem with the Framework, and yep I've had it too :p. Read this:https://parse.com/questions/use-parse-with-objc

Comment: You can also just add Social.framework and Accounts.framework.  Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23253410/parse-starter-project-login-and-register-view-controllers-errors

Answer (score 1):

Same problem happened to me with ParseSDK and cocoapods.
For me, it was an hour waste and three easy steps eventually:

1. Adding the FacebookSDK separately, and then link "Accounts" and "Soacial" frameworks binaries (inside build phases)
2. Link "libstdc++.6.dylib" binary (same way)
3. FacebookSDK.framework already includes the Bolts.framework classes. so removing the additional Bolts.framework from the original ParseSDK

Answer (score 0):

As I'm not using Facebook SDK in my project I simply got rid of `ParseFacebookUtils.framework` and `ParseFacebookUtilsV4.framework`. This solved the problem for me.

PS. It might be required to add `Social`, `libstdc++.6` and `Accounts` frameworks to your project.

PPS. I've kept my `-ObjC` flag in its place