# Trouble adding -ObjC flag to iOS project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, parsing

I have an iOS project which includes the Parse library. It has been working fine.

Today, I needed to add the Google Conversion Tracking SDK to my project. The instructions for adding this SDK require that I change my project settings to include the -ObjC linker flag.

When I did this, I could no longer compile my project. The errors I receive are of the form "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64", and in every case the source of the error is something in the Parse SDK. Here is one example of the 6 errors I'm getting:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter", referenced from:
      -[PF_Twitter getLocalTwitterAccountAsync] in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
```

I've never had to use the -ObjC flag explicitly before. My understanding is that this flag tells the compiler to link every class that was compiled even if it isn't explicitly referenced in the source code. Other than producing a larger executable, I can't see how this would cause a problem.

Appreciate any solutions or ideas.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had a similar issue (not with parse though).
Open PF_Twitter and see what frameworks are included in it's header and implementation files. Then go to your target's Build Phases and add those frameworks in "Link Binary With Libraries".

If this doesn't help, other alternatives are discussed under this stack overflow question--
[Undefined symbols for architecture arm64 Parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23873654/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-arm64-parse)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. Adding the Social framework fixed the problem for me.