# Cocoa pods mach-o error

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

i just installed cocapods for my ios app. After i installed that i keep getting the apple mach-o error. How can i debug or solve this?

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter", referenced from:
      -[PF_Twitter getLocalTwitterAccountAsync] in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
  "_FBTokenInformationExpirationDateKey", referenced from:
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy cacheTokenInformation:] in     Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy expirationDate] in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy setExpirationDate:] in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
  "_FBTokenInformationTokenKey", referenced from:
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy accessToken] in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy setAccessToken:] in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
  "_FBTokenInformationUserFBIDKey", referenced from:
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy facebookId] in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy setFacebookId:] in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ACAccountStore", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBAppCall", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBRequest", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in Parse(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSession", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy", referenced from:
          _OBJC_CLASS_$_PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SLComposeViewController", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SLRequest", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
      "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy", referenced from:
          _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
      "_SLServiceTypeTwitter", referenced from:
          -[PF_Twitter getAccessTokenForReverseAuthAsync:localTwitterAccount:] in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
          -[PF_Twitter getLocalTwitterAccountAsync] in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to use Parse but you are missing some frameworks for twitter and facebook.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23253410/parse-starter-project-login-and-register-view-controllers-errors) has more details